# Reference to variable

Tags: c++, reference

I'm kind of confused about references in C++. Could anyone explain me this :

```
    class Dog
    {
        public:
            Dog( void ) {
                age = 3;
                name = "dummy";
            }

            void setAge( const int & a ) {
                age = a;
            }

         string & getName( void ) {
                return name;
            }

            void print( void ) {
                cout << name << endl;
            }

        private:
            int age;
            string name;

    };

int main( void ) {
    Dog d;
    string & name = d.getName(); // this works and I return reference, so the address of name will be the same as address of name in Dog class.

  int a = 5;
  int & b = a; // why this works? by the logic from before this should not work but the code below should.
  int & c = &a // why this does not work but the code above works?
}
```

Also when i remove `&` and make the function like this `string getName` the code won't work.

Comment: *this works and I return reference, so the address of name will be the same as address of name in Dog class.* Nope.  Don't think of references as pointers.  They can act like them and be implemented with them but they are not pointer.  They are references.

Comment: Some good reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in

Comment: I did not say they are pointers but the addresses of both variables are the same it's not like variable name from main functon has value which is address of variable name from Dog class.

Comment: Consider references as alias.That's it.Don't think about addresses.

Comment: @stilltryingbutstillsofar When you take the address of the reference you get the address of the thing the reference refers to, not the reference itself.  Basically the reference just lets you call a variable a different name, but it is the same variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case

```
 int & b = a;
```

`b` is reference to `a` and memory allocated for data of type `int` is available by both names `a` and `b`.

In case

```
 int & c = &a;
```

you are trying to save address of memory allocated for `a` - result of unary `&` - to `int & c` ... this lead to error.

In case of method

```
 string & getName( void )
```

reference to `string` is returned, so `string & name` (variable in `main`) will provide access to memory of private class member `string name;`